# how to parse "Id"= "name" with python

Tags: python, html, parsing, web-scraping, element

I'm trying to scrap data from a website which has the below element data. I need the Name, Roll No, Marks and Result status. I'm using this code

```
student_data = soup.findAll('div', attrs= {'class':'fontLight'})
```

and

```
for store in student_data:
    name = store.h5.name.text
```

i get error

```
'NoneType' object has no attribute 'name'
```

However. If i try

```
for store in student_data:
    name = store.h5.text
```

I get only the result status which is the last string.

```
'Eligible for Admission,
```

And if I append this

```
for store in student_data:
    name = store.h5.text
    candidate_name.append(name)
```

I get all the data together which I'm unable seperate.

```
['muhammad bilal',
 '346010',
 '193',
 'Eligible for Admission']
```

Is there any way I can get these details separate? please

```
[<div class="row">
 <div class="col-sm-2">
 </div>
 <div class="col-sm-8">
 <h3 class="fontBold">Results 2022  - Result Details</h3>
 <img src="/Documents/Others/Rects.png" style="margin-left:-30px;margin-top:-10px;height:30px;width:420px"/>
 </div>
 <div class="col-sm-2">
 </div>
 </div>,
 <div class="row">
 <div class="col-sm-2">
 </div>
 <div class="col-sm-5">
 <h3 class="fontMedium" style="color:#29a2d8">Student Details</h3>
 <div style="display: flex;">
 <div class="fontBold" style="flex: 1;">
 <h5>Name</h5>
 </div>
 <div class="fontLight" style="flex: 1;">
 <h5 id="name">muhammad bilal</h5>
 </div>
 </div>
 <div style="display: flex;">
 <div class="fontBold" style="flex: 1;">
 <h5>
                                     Student Rollno
                                 </h5>
 </div>
 <div class="fontLight" style="flex: 1;">
 <h5 id="rollno">346010</h5>
 </div>
 </div>
 </div>
 <div class="col-sm-3">
 <h3 class="fontMedium" style="color:#29a2d8">Result</h3>
 <div style="display: flex;">
 <div class="fontBold" style="flex: 1.3;">
 <h5>Obtained Marks</h5>
 </div>
 <div class="fontLight" style="flex: 1;">
 <h5 class="fontMedium" id="omarks">193</h5>
 </div>
 </div>
 <div style="display: flex;">
 <div class="fontBold" style="flex: 1.3;">
 <h5>Result Status</h5>
 </div>
 <div class="fontLight" style="flex: 1;">
 <h5 id="" style="color:green"><b>Eligible for Admission</b></h5>
 </div>
```

Comment: What do you mean by "separate"?  You have a list of 4 separate items that have exactly the information you want.

Comment: Hi Tim, sorry if my question is not clear..
The code supposes to give only the name instead of the whole data in verticle form. I actually need the horizontal format in excel as Name, Roll No., Marks and result. For that, each of them should be separate to generate clean excel sheet.

Answer (score 1):

You can check on the id and value like this:

```
for store in student_data:
    id = store.h5.attrs['id']
    value = store.h5.text
    print(id, value)
```

Then you can use if statements to check the id's. For example,

```
for store in student_data:
    id = store.h5.attrs['id']
    value = store.h5.text
    if id == "name":
       print(value)
```

Does this answer your question?

Comment: Thanks, Dave it worked.

However, I'm now facing a new problem related to this new code.  

Pls check the below link if you can help further. Thanks 

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74635007/problem-with-attrid-append-pd-dataframe